# C# WPF PRISM - Pass multiple parameters to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am using the PRISM framework for my C# WPF application. The UserControl is inheriting from the IDialogAware Interface. What I'm trying to do, is passing multiple parameters from the MainWindowViewModel to the UserControlViewModel. But when i the OnDialogOpened Method is called, and I'm trying to fill the parameter1, there is an System.FormatException because the value I'm getting from parameters.GetValue("parameter1") is:

*"false, parameter2=False"*

Sure, I could solve it with the substring() method, but isn't there a nicer or better way?

**MainWindowViewModel:**

```
_dialogService.ShowDialog("SecondUserControl", 
        new DialogParameters($"parameter1={parameter1}, parameter2={parameter2}"), r =>
        {});
```

**UserControlViewModel:**

```
public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
{
  var parameter1 = parameters.GetValue<bool>("parameter1");
  var parameter2 = parameters.GetValue<bool>("parameter2");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DialogParameters` inherits [`ParametersBase`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/342689ba9a10e511418943438d0f5c57534ca623/src/Prism.Core/Common/ParametersBase.cs) which implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` and has methods typical for collections like `Add(string key, object value)` so you can create new instance and insert your parameters or just initialize a new instance with collection initializer.  I found an example in ["Using dialog service"](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dialogs/dialog-service.html#using-the-dialog-service) par of official documentation:

```
var parameters = new DialogParameters();
parameters.Add("parameter1", value1);
parameters.Add("parameter2", value2);

// or

var parameters = new DialogParameters
    {
        { "parameter1", value1 },
        { "parameter2", value2 }
    };

_dialogService.ShowDialog("SecondUserControl", parameters, r => {});
```